# Check and send messages to mobile devices in the same lan

Tags: javascript, cordova

I would like to develope an hybrid mobile app using Cordova and JavaScript. I would like to know if it is possible using these technologies to scan devices connected on the same lan and possibly send messages to them (of course they need the same application on device) so something like sockets etc. .

Comment: I have never done that but i think it is possible since you can access an http/web-socket server from one pc to another when they're connected to the same LAN. But about the scanning, I have absolutely no idea, sorry :(